# Finding Shear Force in a Beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, structural-beam

I have the following question:

[image]

The question is asking for the shear force at point C. To work this out, I've determined the reaction force at point A. To find the shear force, the book then sums the forces in the Y direction.  It says $\sum F_y = 0$; $5\:\mathrm{kN}-V_c = 0$, $V_c = 5\:\mathrm{kN}$. Why aren't the 10kN force and reaction force at B counted in this?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.